# Homing Out of Activity Causes Dialog Boxes Not To Appear When Restarted

Tags: android, dialog, android-lifecycle

I've been poking around at this problem and I can't seem to figure it out.  I have a simple app with a few normal views and a GL surface view, I make a few dialog boxes using onCreateDialog() and everything seems fine.

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{
     super.onCreateDialog(id);

     Dialog m_Dialog = null;

     // help dialog
     if (id == HELP_DIALOG)
     {
        m_Dialog = new Dialog(this);
        m_Dialog.setContentView(R.layout.help_dialog);
        m_Dialog.setTitle("Instructions - Press BACK to close");
     }
 }
```

However if I use home to exit the app then go back into the app the dialogs no longer appear, however the screen dims as if the dialog was being displayed.  I am getting the call to onPrepareDialog() even when the dialog does not show, I tried some things in there like calling show() off of the dialog.  It gets a bit more strange, if I then switch to my GL surface view and back the dialogs work again.  I am using a ViewAnimator to switch between my views.  I am pretty sure I am handling the lifecycle correctly, over riding onPause() / onResume()

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    m_Sensors.StartSensors();       
    m_GameThread.Pause(false);
    glSurface.onResume();
}
```

As always, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried working with GL on android, but I have experienced some home button/re-open app weirdness myself recently - in my case it turned out to be connected to the issues below, which you might want to check out:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5277

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2373

Hope it can help you get on the right track.